# Do I need to synchronize writeObject()?

Tags: java, serialization

I have some objects which are accessed concurrently by RMI serialization. Recently I had written custom serialization methods:

```
/** This method is made to omit serialization of this.order */
private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out)
  throws java.io.IOException
{
    Order tmpOrder = this.order;
    this.order = null;
    out.defaultWriteObject();
    this.order = tmpOrder;
}

private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in)
  throws java.io.IOException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    in.defaultReadObject();
}
```

I don't want to permit to spoil this.order by concurrent RMI thread.

1. Do I need to make writeObject synchronized ?   or
2. Does the RMI framework do all the best to synchronize the access to the object ?

In second case my synchronization could even cause deadlocks in RMI. The general contract of JAVA API is that a method is called by one thread except noted specifically. So if I should follow the rule I should leave the `writeObject` w/o any synchronization. Is this correct ?

Another solution to my problem without answering the question is certainly declaring `private static final ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields`. (I cannot make a field transient because the object is not only a DTO but an JPA Entity also)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have some objects which are accessed concurrently by RMI
>   serialization

No you don't. You have some objects that are accessed concurrently by *Object Serialization.*

> Does the RMI framework do all the best to synchronize the access to the object?

No. The Object Serialization framework might, but it isn't specified.

Comment: Thanks for giving me more details about JAVA Serialization API :-) . So I can see I don't have anything to worry about in the code snipset above. ;-)

Comment: @digital_infinity Have you considered making `order` transient, and getting rid of both your `readObject()` and `writeObject()` methods?

Comment: Yeah that's why I have written the last paragraph of my question ;-) . The object is used by Hibernate and it cannot be transient (java keyword).

Answer (score 1):

Attempting to serialise objects that are being used concurrently is going to lead to a mess. Certainly to read a consistent state or even a well-formed state you will generally need exclusive locking. If `writeObject` is syncrhonised, then you have extreme problems making sure the lock-ordering is well behaved.

Adding `serialPersistentFields` (spelt correctly:) should have the same behaviour as making fields `transient`. Making `order` `transient` will stop it being written out, which seems to be what you are attempting in the question code. Using `ObjectOutputStream.putFields` can also achieve something similar.

Comment: Actually besides serialization I synchronize the objects on my own. When the objects are going to be serialized, they are not changed anymore. 
There are some cases when distinct object is sent to few recipients in the same time by different threads client RMI calls (my side is the RMI client for a few RMI servers). That was why I had some doubts about synchronization issues while serialization.

Comment: @digital_infinity So if your `writeObject` mutates the object and you may have multiple threads calling the method on the same object, then that will need some locking with all the issues that entails. (Also, as written it's not exception-safe.)

Comment: So you tell me that EJP's answer is not correct ?
The Object Serialization is the magic box that makes synchronization. I cannot synchronize on my own here because my synchronization is going to interfere with the Object Serialization's synchronization and could possibly cause deadlocks. Imagine serializing of array of my objects.

Comment: Of course I can try to synchronize the RMI sending threads externally outside the `writeObject` method. The question is: Is it necessary ?

Comment: I am using the following logic: 
1. It should not be necessary to synchronize RMI method calls if RMI is really thread safe. I assume it is, so it should do the synchronization on its part. 
2. If writeObject() should be multi-thread (thread safe method) it should be denoted somewhere. Generally in JAVA API if something is not denoted as thread safe, no one should try to use this without synchronization. 

Although you work in Oracle so I am open to your suggestions. ;-)

Comment: @digital_infinity RMI is not thread safe. RMI isn't relevant to this question at all. It is Object Serialization that you are interested in.

Comment: @EJP Although RMI overrides ObjectOutputStream in some way. I am not sure how. I know that in case of RMI server method implementation is not thread safe and must be synchronized on server but potentially on client side different client programs could call the same RMI method. 

Let's discuss the client side. If we have one client with many threads. Should the call to the same server method from different threads of one client be synchronized too ?

Comment: @EJP I know you removed me RMI tag from my question but I think it is important to have bigger picture here. RMI modifies Object Serialization in a slight way.

Comment: @digital_infinity RMI overrides `ObjectOutputStream` to provide annotations on where classes should be dynamically loaded from. There's not really any useful thread-safety in `ObjectOutputStream` other to impose [weird] security constraints.

Comment: @tackline - thanks a lot. (I know I am changing topic to RMI synchronization).  Does it mean I should synchronize access to the same object stub on **RMI client** event if I want to access _different methods_ on the stub from _different threads_ ?

Comment: @digital_infinity (a) RMI doesn't modify Object Serialization in any *relevant* way. (b) You don't need to synchronize access to an RMI stub. The stub is thread-safe.

Comment: @EJP (b) This is my state of the knowledge too ;-) Thanks for the confirmation. I wrote some high efficient programs that worked great without any concurrency problem, but nobody knows - maybe hardware synchronized something. I have seen a program (no my code) which worked great on Intel multi core processors and hung on AMD multi-cores, probably because something was synchronized differently on processor hardware level.